# Inserting data to sqlite (second table with foreign key)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am facing some difficulties in inserting the data in sqlite. The application is quiz application, where user need to have a username first (w/out password) then the score can be viewed later on. Before do the quiz user has to create username first (if new user) then choose the username (all the usernames will be listed), so user needs to click the related username. The username (almag table) can be inserted successfully, but not for score table. Two tables are linked with foreign key which are userId. when user finished the quiz and press certain button (menu button), I want the score will be saved automatically, but I am still facing difficulties to do so.. I hope someone can help.

These are some codes of the application.

Database java file

```
public class DatabaseUsername extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="use.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;
private View _id;
public DatabaseUsername(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}   
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE almag (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, jekel TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE score (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, score INTEGER, userId INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES almag(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);"); //create table score
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // no-op, since will not be called until 2nd schema
    // version exists
}
public Cursor getAll() {
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, nama, jekel FROM almag ORDER BY nama",null));
}
public Cursor getById(String id) {
    String[] args={id};
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, nama, jekel FROM almag WHERE _ID=?",args));
}
public void insert(String nama, String jekel) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nama", nama);
    cv.put("jekel", jekel);     
    getWritableDatabase().insert("almag", "nama", cv);
}
public void insertScore (int _id, int score) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();   
    cv.put("_id", _id);
    cv.put("score", score);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("score", "score", cv);
}
public void setUsername(View _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}
public String getNama(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(1));
}
public String getJekel(Cursor c) {
    return(c.getString(2));
}
}
```

TheEndActivity

```
public class TheEndActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

DatabaseUsername helper=null;
private int _id;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.theendactivitylayout);
    helper=new DatabaseUsername(this);
    final SetGame currentGame = ((TheApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
    String result = "Your Score is " + currentGame.getRight() + "/" + currentGame.getNumRounds() + ".. ";
    String comment = Mark.getResultComment(currentGame.getRight(), currentGame.getNumRounds(), getDifficultySettings());    
    
    TextView results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endgameResult);
    results.setText(result + comment);
    
    int image = Mark.getResultImage(currentGame.getRight(), currentGame.getNumRounds(), getDifficultySettings());
    ImageView resultImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.resultPage);
    resultImage.setImageResource(image);
    
    Button finishBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finishBtn);
    Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answerBtn);
    finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
            Intent i = new Intent(TheEndActivity.this, QuizAppActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            helper.insertScore(_id, currentGame.getRight());
    }
    });
    
    answerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                        
                Intent i = new Intent(TheEndActivity.this, AnsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, AppRule.PLAYBUTTON);
        }
        });
    
}

private int getDifficultySettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(AppRule.SETTINGS, 0);
    int diff = settings.getInt(AppRule.DIFFICULTY, 2);
    return diff;
}


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    switch (keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
        return true;
    }
    
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }}
```

UsernameList

```
public class UsernameList extends ListActivity {
public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.rika.fyp.player";
Cursor model=null;
AlmagAdapter adapter=null;
EditText nama=null;
RadioGroup jekel=null;
DatabaseUsername helper=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.usernamelist);
    
    helper=new DatabaseUsername(this);
    
    nama=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nama);
    jekel=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.jekel); 
    model=helper.getAll();
    startManagingCursor(model);
    adapter=new AlmagAdapter(model);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    
    helper.close();
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view,int position, long id) {
    
    helper.setUsername(nama);
    Intent i=new Intent(UsernameList.this, QuizAppActivity.class);

    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivity(i);
}       

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option, menu);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.add) {
        startActivity(new Intent(UsernameList.this, UsernameRegister.class));
        
        return(true);
    }
    
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String type=null;
        
        switch (jekel.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
            case R.id.pria:
                type="Pria";
                break;
            case R.id.perempuan:
                type="Perempuan";
                break;
            
        }
        
        helper.insert(nama.getText().toString(), type);

        model.requery();
    }
};

class AlmagAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    AlmagAdapter(Cursor c) {
        super(UsernameList.this, c);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,Cursor c) {
        AlmagHolder holder=(AlmagHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }
    
    @Override
    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.usernamerow, parent, false);
        AlmagHolder holder=new AlmagHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }
}

static class AlmagHolder {
    private TextView nama=null;
    private TextView alamat=null;
    private ImageView icon=null;
    private View row=null;
    
    AlmagHolder(View row) {
        this.row=row;
        
        nama=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }
    
    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DatabaseUsername helper) {
        nama.setText(helper.getNama(c));
        if (helper.getJekel(c).equals("Pria")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.pria);
        }
        else if (helper.getJekel(c).equals("Perempuan")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.perempuan);
        }
        
    }
}}
```

I got these in the logcat

> ERROR/Database(319): Error inserting score=20 _id=0
>
> ERROR/Database(319): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Comment: `cv.put("_id", _id);` in `insertScore (int _id, int score)` doesn't looks good .... shouldn't be `cv.put("_id", userId);` in `insertScore (int userId, int score)` ...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the logcat?

Answer (score -1):

Your `onCreate()` method looks overly complicated. Try this instead:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE almag (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nama TEXT, jekel TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE score (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, score INTEGER, userId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES almag(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);"); //create table score
}
```

I can't guarantee it will fix your problem, but simplicity has a way of clearing up things.

Also try changing your insert methods to this:

```
public void insert(String nama, String jekel) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nama", nama);
    cv.put("jekel", jekel);     
    getWritableDatabase().insert("almag", null, cv);
}

public void insertScore (int _id, int score) {
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();   
    cv.put("_id", _id);
    cv.put("score", score);
    getWritableDatabase().insert("score", null, cv);
}
```

Comment: yup, but don't give effect for the problem. I think the problem is the way to insert the score, but i dunno how to fix it